# Ribbon menu blank space

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

i created this simple wxWidgets app in wxFormbuilder:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, there is a weird blank space on the ribbon menus tabs. Is there anything i'm missing? It would definetly be better to have the ribbon menu align straight to the top left. In case anybody wants it, here is the code generated by wxFormbuilder:

```
this->SetSizeHints( wxSize( 183,146 ), wxDefaultSize );

wxBoxSizer* bSizer4;
bSizer4 = new wxBoxSizer( wxVERTICAL );

m_ribbonBar1 = new wxRibbonBar( this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxRIBBON_BAR_DEFAULT_STYLE );
m_ribbonBar1->SetArtProvider(new wxRibbonAUIArtProvider); 
m_ribbonPage1 = new wxRibbonPage( m_ribbonBar1, wxID_ANY, wxT("File") , wxNullBitmap , 0 );
m_ribbonBar1->SetActivePage( m_ribbonPage1 ); 
m_ribbonPanel1 = new wxRibbonPanel( m_ribbonPage1, wxID_ANY, wxT("File") , wxNullBitmap , wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxRIBBON_PANEL_DEFAULT_STYLE );
m_rbtnBar = new wxRibbonButtonBar( m_ribbonPanel1, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
m_rbtnBar->AddButton( wxID_ANY, wxT("New"), wxNullBitmap, wxEmptyString);
m_rbtnBar->AddButton( wxID_ANY, wxT("Save"), wxNullBitmap, wxEmptyString);
m_rbtnBar->AddButton( wxID_ANY, wxT("Load"), wxNullBitmap, wxEmptyString);
m_ribbonPage2 = new wxRibbonPage( m_ribbonBar1, wxID_ANY, wxT("View") , wxNullBitmap , 0 );
m_ribbonBar1->SetActivePage( m_ribbonPage2 ); 
m_ribbonPanel21 = new wxRibbonPanel( m_ribbonPage2, wxID_ANY, wxT("View") , wxNullBitmap , wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxRIBBON_PANEL_DEFAULT_STYLE );
m_ribbonButtonBar21 = new wxRibbonButtonBar( m_ribbonPanel21, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
m_ribbonButtonBar21->AddButton( wxID_ANY, wxT("Do something"), wxNullBitmap, wxEmptyString);
m_ribbonButtonBar21->AddButton( wxID_ANY, wxT("Do something else"), wxNullBitmap, wxEmptyString);
m_ribbonBar1->Realize();

bSizer4->Add( m_ribbonBar1, 0, wxEXPAND, 5 );

wxBoxSizer* mainSizer;
mainSizer = new wxBoxSizer( wxVERTICAL );

m_ntbkMain = new wxNotebook( this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
m_panel1 = new wxPanel( m_ntbkMain, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTAB_TRAVERSAL );
wxBoxSizer* bSizer6;
bSizer6 = new wxBoxSizer( wxHORIZONTAL );

wxBoxSizer* bSizer7;
bSizer7 = new wxBoxSizer( wxVERTICAL );

m_button11 = new wxButton( m_panel1, wxID_ANY, wxT("MyButton"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
bSizer7->Add( m_button11, 0, wxALL, 5 );

m_button12 = new wxButton( m_panel1, wxID_ANY, wxT("MyButton"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
bSizer7->Add( m_button12, 0, wxALL, 5 );

m_button13 = new wxButton( m_panel1, wxID_ANY, wxT("MyButton"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
bSizer7->Add( m_button13, 0, wxALL, 5 );


bSizer6->Add( bSizer7, 1, wxEXPAND, 5 );


m_panel1->SetSizer( bSizer6 );
m_panel1->Layout();
bSizer6->Fit( m_panel1 );
m_ntbkMain->AddPage( m_panel1, wxT("Tab 1"), true );
m_panel2 = new wxPanel( m_ntbkMain, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTAB_TRAVERSAL );
m_ntbkMain->AddPage( m_panel2, wxT("a page"), false );
m_panel3 = new wxPanel( m_ntbkMain, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTAB_TRAVERSAL );
m_ntbkMain->AddPage( m_panel3, wxT("a page"), false );
m_panel4 = new wxPanel( m_ntbkMain, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTAB_TRAVERSAL );
m_ntbkMain->AddPage( m_panel4, wxT("a page"), false );

mainSizer->Add( m_ntbkMain, 1, wxEXPAND, 5 );


bSizer4->Add( mainSizer, 1, wxEXPAND, 5 );


this->SetSizer( bSizer4 );
this->Layout();

this->Centre( wxBOTH );
```

## This is what i want to achieve:

[image: office 2007 button]

Comment: What is you wx and Windows version? Can you reproduce this in the sample?

Comment: @Igor Windows 10 Education 64-Bit, wxWidgets 3.1.0 built from source. I haven't tried, this is simply the way it looks in the wxFormbuilder designer aswell.

Comment: try the sample. if it works, see what is different with you code. if it doesn't - well, post to wx-dev or open a ticket on trac.wxwidgets.org. Also, try the actual compiled app binary - sometimes RAD tool can be misleading.

Answer (score 3):

This is the normal behaviour of `wxRibbonBar`. The space is intended for a user provided file menu, or the kind of circle icon that used to be in MS Office applications when `wxRibbonBar` was implemented (see http://www.corsix.org/gsoc/ribbon.html).

One way of providing the [now more common] "File" menu in this space is to derive your own art provider from `wxRibbonMSWArtProvider` (or one of the other providers). You need to override `::DrawTabCtrlBackground`.

The following is a simple example:

```
void myArtProvider::DrawTabCtrlBackground(
                        wxDC& dc,
                        wxWindow* WXUNUSED(wnd),
                        const wxRect& rect)
{
    // Draw the background for the whole tab area.
    dc.SetPen(*wxTRANSPARENT_PEN);
    dc.SetBrush(m_tab_ctrl_background_brush);
    dc.DrawRectangle(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);

    // Draw the "File" menu background, unfortunately its static and doesn't change when hovered.
    dc.SetBrush (wxColour(35, 70, 135));
    dc.DrawRectangle (rect.x, rect.y, 60, rect.height);
    dc.SetFont (m_tab_label_font);

    // Centre the "File" text in the available space (alternatively this could use wxDC::DrawLabel).
    dc.SetTextForeground (*wxWHITE);
    int text_height;
    int text_width;
    dc.GetTextExtent ("File", &text_width, &text_height);
    int y = rect.y + ((rect.height - text_height) / 2);

    // Draw the "File" text.
    dc.DrawText("File", rect.x + ((60 - text_width) / 2) + 1, y);
}
```

You then need to bind the wxRibbonBar `wxEVT_LEFT_DOWN` event to a handler function that does whatever you want to happen when you click on "File" (i.e. show a popup menu or a whole new page like the latest versions of Office).

The result is something like this:
[wxRibbonBar with "File" menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1vNE.png)

Comment: how can i get an office-2010-like button at the corner of the window then?

Comment: Please could you add an image to your question showing what you would like to achieve. Do you mean a kind of gradient button rather than the flat button that I showed?

Comment: i updated the question. And sorry, i meant office-2007-like.

Comment: AFAIK that is an altogether more complex thing. To make it look like this you would need to have your wxFrame without the wxCAPTION style and draw the entire top part of the frame yourself. You would also need to handle mouse clicks and drags to allow the window to be moved. What is more, I am not sure that a wxCAPTION-less style works on all platforms. Probably this should be another question along the lines of "How to have a owner drawn title bar in wxWidgets"